# Read text file using OpenMP

Tags: performance, io, openmp, mmap

I'm trying to optimize reading text file with array of floats.

It would be great to parallelize this process. One possible way might be to use `mmap`. However I don't know how implement it, cause it's seems unclear how to divide file especially if float numbers have different format like: `1.0 123.23 0.1145` and so on.

If there are any other suggestion how to optimize speed of reading I would be glad to hear them.

Thank you for any response!

Comment: Unless you have the right hardware don't waste your time trying to parallelise reading from disk.  Think of what happens as multiple processes / threads contend for access to the single drive head on your disk.

Answer (score 1):

Find out first where is the bottleneck. In my experience, reading floats from text files might be slow not because of slow I/O but because of parsing text numbers. If this is your case, it might help to read the whole file as a text into memory (by a single process; there is likely no benefit of parallelization here) and then parse it by multiple threads in parallel.